# Avoiding SAXParseException in Scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

Im having difficulties avoiding a SAXParseException when parsing XML files.

The reason is that I am parsing thousands of thousands of XML files and sometimes the XML file contains errors in it.

Im wondering if there is a way to skip these XML files and continue with the ones that are correctly built.

Cheers!

Comment: It's difficult to help without context details. But common idea for any decision is `Try(...).recover{case err: SAXParseException => ...}`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an RDD[String] and you parse string into XML

```
rdd.flatMap{ s => 
   try {
      parse(s) // here you convert the string into your XML
   } catch {
      case SAXParseException() => 
         logError(...)
         None
   }
}
```

Here the flatmap will behave like a map plus a filter. It fill filter our all the xmls that fail parsing. You can log them or just discard them.

If you want to do something smarter with your exception you can take a look at a great tutorial about scala [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html)